# Django SQL get query returns a <key, value> hashmap, how to access the value?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am using django 1.10 and python 3.6.1

when executing 
`get_or_none(models.Character, pk=0)`, with SQL's get method, the query returns a hashmap i.e.: `<Character: example>`

How can I extract the value example?

I tried .values(), I tried iterating, I tried .Character
nothing seems to work, and I can't find a solution in the documentation.

Thank you,

Comment: are you sure you have a row with 0 as the id? ??

Comment: Yes, and it's returning a value. The value it's returning is <Character: sage> that's literally taken from my DB. The column name is Character and the value is sage. I want to be able to save sage as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: That is not a "hashmap", by which I suppose you mean a dictionary. That is an instance of the Character model, and you access its properties with dot notation just like you would in Java.

Answer (score 0):

get_or_none or returns model object or None if id does not exists. You an access it like any other model object and access it fields and methods

```
character = get_or_none(models.Character, pk=0)
character.some_field
```

if it is none you will get error if you try to access field

Comment: That's what I thought, in fact in my quest I said I tried to access it that way.
But it gives me the following error: 'Character' object has no attribute 'Character'

which makes sense.
But I just want to add the character i.e. 'example' to a dictionary. So I need to strip down <Character: example> to just 'example'

Comment: Why are you trying to access a "Character" property? Does your Character model have that property? You should show your model definition.

Comment: @DanielRoseman THANK YOU. I just understood what I was doing wrong. Basically I didn't know I had to access the field inside of Character model. I was treating it as a dictionary on its own.

PS: I'm an SQL newbie, that's why.

Make it an answer and I'll mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
try:
    obj = Character.objects.get(pk=1)
    character = obj.somefield
except Character.DoesNotExist:
    character = None
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Roseman helped me understand the answer.

SOLVED:

What I was getting from the query was the model of character, so I couldn't have accessed it thru result.Character but thru result.Field_Inside_Of_Character